# iOS crashed when user recieved notification using flutter

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Flutter to build my project at the moment all the code works except on iOS when the user receives a notification.

When the notification is recieved when the app is in the background and when the user tries to click on the notification or even click on the app (or return to the App) the app immediately crashes and i have tried many alternative to make it work but its not working out

**What have tried**

1. Invalidate Caches and Restart the Project
2. flutter pub cache clean
3. I have updated all the firebase packages to the latest
4. Update the GoogleService-Info

I even had to add Firebase Crashlytic to know why the app is craching, so far nothing its coming up regarding why the app is crashing but every other error is been reported.

**Package of Interest**

```
  firebase_core: ^2.27.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.8
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.19
  firebase_database: ^10.4.9
  awesome_notifications_core: ^0.9.1 
  awesome_notifications: any

  firebase_analytics: ^10.8.9
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.4.18
```

Please, how can i handle this issues?